# Angular 6 tree shakeable providers and lazy modules

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular v6 we have this new feature where we can define the provider scope via the Injectable decorator.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CounterService {
  num = Math.random();
}
```

Does this also solve the problem of lazy load modules getting a different instance? (`forRoot()`)

Answer (score 2):

It does, only if you inject your service in the **root**, given that *Treeshakeable Injector* resolution logic doesn't work in a lazy loaded scenario.

You can see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23715#issuecomment-386826526)